# CANNOT GET api/items (from Pluralsight Express/React Tutorial)

Tags: javascript, express, gulp

I've been working through the React, Express, FLUX tutorial. 
But seem to be hitting the curb with a CANNOT GET error for my api data.

[image: FILE STRUCTURE]

Server > Routes > items.js:

```
module.exports = function (app) {

  var items = [{
    name: "Ice Cream"
    }, {
      name: "Waffles"
    }, {
      name: "Candy",
      purchased: true
    }, {
      name: "Snarks"
    }];



  app.route('/api/items')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.send(items);
    })

};
```

While main.js is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('./../app/index.ejs',{});
})
  .use(express.static(__dirname + '/../.tmp'))
  .listen(7777);

require('./routes/items')(app);
```

I also have a gulpfile to configure and suspect this is where the issue is. But i cannot for the life of me figure this one out. Help!

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var LiveServer = require('gulp-live-server');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');

var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('live-server', function() {
    var server = new LiveServer('server/main.js');
    server.start();
});

gulp.task('bundle', ['copy'], function() {
    return browserify({
        entries: 'app/main.jsx',
        debug: true
    })
      .transform(reactify)
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('app.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./.tmp'));
});

gulp.task('copy', function() {
    gulp.src(['app/*.css'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./.tmp'));
});

gulp.task('serve', ['bundle', 'live-server'], function() {
    browserSync.init(null,{
        proxy:"http://localhost:7777",
        port: 9001
    })
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess, but do you have to apply your custom routes *before* starting the app?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Thanks anyway - but i realised it was a `node killall` issue. The port 7777 was already in use somehow. Killed it, restarted and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did a `killall node` restarted and it was fine. Apparently some sort of cache'ing or `EARDINUSE` issue.